# Django custom admin view like history

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I need to add a custom view to a model admin similar to the history view. For example if I have a model called Job I can access the history by going to /jobs/job//history/. How do I add another view that will respond to a pattern like /jobs/job//workflow/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [`get_urls()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) on your Admin to add more admin views.

- don't forget the `admin_view()` wrapper
- if you wanted to add a view for an individual object (like the change form), just add the object id to your url pattern, then in your view (try to) grab the corresponding object.

It's up to you to provide the links (for example, by overriding the base (`/change_form`) template and adding a new item to the "object-tools" list).